# If a map induces the identity on homology, does it also on cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology

Suppose we have a continuous map $f: X \to X$ such that $f_*: H_n(X) \to H_n(X)$ is the identity for all $n$. Is it true that in this case $f^*$ will be the identity on $H^n(X; G)$ for all $n$ and $G$? Does it hold when we additionally assume that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence?

Note that the first idea to simply use the naturality from the universal coefficient theorem does not work: Take for example the exact sequence
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2  \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
if we choose $g: \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ to send $(0, 1) \mapsto (1, 1)$, we can build a short commutative ladder with the identity on the left and right sides and $g$ in the middle. (The 5-lemma only implies that $g$ has to be an isomorphism.)

As a second, similar question suppose we have another map $g: Y \to Y$ that also induces the identity on homology. Will $(f \times g)_*$ be the identity on $H_n(X \times Y)$? Does the naturality from the Künneth formula help with this? (Of course similarly, what about cohomology?)

*To provide a bit of context:* I encountered this problem in reading Spanier's chapter on the Serre spectral sequence. The setting is as follows. We suppose that $p: E \to B$ is a fibration, $b_0 \in B$ and $F = p^{-1}(b_0)$. He calls $p$ *orientable* if for any loop $\gamma$ at $b_0$ in $B$ the associated homotopy equivalence of fibers $f: F \to F$ the induced map on homology $f_*$ is the identity. This is used to derive theorem 9.2.13. However, for the various analogues needed in section 9.4 the above statements seem necessary to me. I think there is no remark about using field coefficients or something like that.

Comment: Doesn't the [Universal Coefficient Theorem for cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology) give the result you want? (Note that the restriction to modules over a PID includes arbitrary abelian groups viewed as modules over $\Bbb{Z}$.) If I'm wrong, then I think you need to give more details about your proposed counter-example.

Comment: What I was trying to convey with my counterexample is the following: in a "ladder" of short exact sequences the outer two maps don't determine the middle one, in particular, the outer two being identity maps does not imply that the one in the middle is. Now imagine my sequence coming from the universal coefficient theorem applied to some space $X$ with $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and there being some $f: X \to X$ that induces the identity on $H_*(X)$ but $f^* = g$ on $H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: It would be good if you could come up with a specific counter-example. In the mean time, I need to have a look at Spanier (my recollection is that he is very thorough about this kind of thing - but that doesn't mean that he has missed something here).

Comment: I wonder why Spanier declined to set up the Serre spectral sequence using systems of local coefficients. I think his choice of using oriented fibrations is precisely to avoid this. Other references on the spectral sequence should use the more general setup. McCleary's *User's Guide to Spectral Sequences* is one possible resource.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $X=S^3\vee\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2$ and consider the following map $f:X\to X$.  On the $S^3$ summand, $f$ is the identity.  On the $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2$ summand, $f$ is the composition of the pinch map $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2\to \Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2\vee \Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2$ with the map $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2\vee \Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2\to S^3\vee\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2$ which is the identity on the second summand and on the first summand is the map $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2\to S^3$ that collapses the $2$-skeleton to a point.

To see that this $f$ induces the identity on homology, note that the only nontrivial reduced homology of $X$ is $H_2(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$ via the $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2$ summand and $H_3(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ via the $S^3$ summand.  So the induced map on $H_2$ can be computed by projecting down to just the $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2$ summand, and the induced map on $H_3$ can be computed by projecting down to just the $S^3$ summand, and $f$ becomes the identity in both cases.

However, $f$ does not induce the identity on cohomology.  Indeed, $H^3(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ with the summands corresponding to the summands of $X$, and then $f^*$ maps $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$ since the map $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2\to S^3$ used in the construction of $f$ maps $1\in H^3(S^3;\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ to $1\in H^3(\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2;\mathbb{Z})$.

This is also an example of a map that induces the identity on homology with integer coefficients but not arbitrary coefficients, since the map $\Sigma\mathbb{RP}^2\to S^3$ is also nontrivial on homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2$.  Since there is a natural isomorphism $\tilde{H}_*(X\wedge\mathbb{RP}^2;\mathbb{Z})\cong \tilde{H}_{*-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}/2)$, this also gives a counterexample to your second question about products: $f\times 1:X\times\mathbb{RP}^2\to X\times\mathbb{RP}^2$ does not induce the identity on homology with integer coefficients.

(To provide some motivation, the starting point here is the observation that the obvious map of chain complexes from $0\to\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{2}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ to $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to 0\to 0$ induces the $0$ map on homology but not on cohomology.  Calling these chain complexes $Y$ and $Z$, you can then add this map to the identity map $Y\oplus Z\to Y\oplus Z$ to get a map $Y\oplus Z\to Y\oplus Z$ which is the identity on homology but not on cohomology.  The topological example above is then just a way to realize this map of chain complexes with the homology of an actual space; the chain complexes $Y$ and $Z$ correspond to the spaces $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and $S^2$ but you have to suspend once in order to be able to add together maps on the level of spaces.)

Comment: Thank you for the example! Is $f$ a homotopy equivalence?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a homotopy equivalence since $X$ is simply connected and $f$ induces an isomorphism on homology.

Comment: @EricWofsey when your rep reaches the capacity of an Int32, do you think it will over flow back to $0$? 

Comment: +1, especially for the parenthetical conclusion.